# How do I use antivirus software to scan a Windows machine using bootable Linux?

Tags: anti-virus, puppylinux

How can I install Avast or any other anti-virus program onto a USB bootable Puppy Linux?

I need to scan Windows machines using it.

Comment: I did not know you could install anti-virus software on Linux.

Comment: I think you are wanting to create a linux bootable USB drive that will scan a Windows machine with Avast, is that right?

Comment: @rmart I did not think of that, and now it all makes sense.

Comment: see: http://www.murga-linux.com/puppy/viewtopic.php?t=58277 Too much to quote and I don't use Puppy myself, so no answer

Comment: I think you are wanting to create a linux bootable USB drive that will scan a Windows machine with Avast, is that right? Yes that is correct.

Comment: @ImagingScientist - You should edit your question to include these details, and any others you might have.  It's a poor question at the moment.

Comment: @Shinrai I did this for him, hope this is what he meant. I also added "any other" because Avast is Windows software.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to scan your windows machine for viruses, then you can use one of many bootable antivirus rescue ISO's. These can be used on USB's as well including the ability to update (Over Ethernet or Linux compatible Wireless Adapter)

You can use:

- [Avira Antivir Rescue System](http://www.avira.com/en/support-download-avira-antivir-rescue-system)
- [BitDefender Rescue](http://kb.bitdefender.com/site/article/627/)
- [Kaspersky Rescue Disk](http://support.kaspersky.com/viruses/rescuedisk)
- [Panda SafeCD](http://research.pandasecurity.com/panda-safecd-4-4-3-0/)

That's just some of many.

If you are adamant to install an antivirus on puppylinux then you need to make sure you have a persistent USB bootable image and then install one of the following:

- [F-Prot Antivirus](http://www.f-prot.com/download/home_user/download_fplinux.html)
- [ClamAV](http://www.clamav.net/lang/en/download/packages/packages-linux/)
- [AVG](http://free.avg.com/us-en/download.prd-alf)

Comment: Thanks for the post. Will try these bootable Anti-virus solutions  instead of trying to get Puppy Linux to install Avast.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Fedora LiveUSB-Creator. Then install Avast rpm http://www.avast.com/es-ww/Linux-home-edition#tab4 in the USB. Then just update the antivirus, mount and scan the Windows partitions.

Comment: Already got puppy Linux working on the USB, but had no luck trying to install Avast.